# Python: Dictionnary to web file list

Tags: python, web, filelist

I have a dict representation of a filesystem, which looks like this.

```
{
    "en": {
        'file_name_1': [{meta representation of file_name_1}] or False,
        {'folder_name': {
            'index': [{meta repr. of the index}] or False
            'sub_file_1': [{meta repr. of file_name_1}] or False,
            }
        }
    }
    "fr": {
        <...>
    }
    'tree_root': path to the tree's parent node
}
```

Given the path to one leaf in this tree (file or folder), I would like to represent the tree leading to that leaf as HTML nested lists.

I do not believe my tree will ever become very deep, but for the sake of being fast, I am considering running only once through the path of the leaf.

Here is what I have now: (`self.tree` is my dictionary, `leaf_path` my, hmm. leaf path. I tried and cleaned my code for simplicity)

```
rel_URI = [key for key in leaf_path.split(os.sep)]
stack = []

html = u'<ul>'
for key in rel_URI:
    stack.append(key)
    obj = reduce(dict.get, stack, self.tree)
    if isinstance(obj, dict): # a subdir
        html += u'<ul>'
        for _dir in obj.iterkeys() if isinstance(_dir, dict):
            if _dir == rel_URI[len(stack)]: # in the leaf_path
                html += u'<li class="folder">%s</li>' % self.getTitle(obj, _dir)
            else: # not in the leaf_path
                html += u'<li class="folder, far">%s</li>'% self.getTitle(obj,_dir)
        for _file in obj.iterkeys() if isinstance(_file, list):
            html += u'<li class="file, far">%s</li>'% obj[0]['title']
        html += u'</ul>'
    else: # the leaf file
        item = u'<li class="file">%s</li>' % obj[0]['title']
html += '</ul>'
```

I have trouble figuring out how to nest the next sub-tree into the iteration: the way it is I have entirely disconnected the next step from this one, and so I end up with a messed-up nested file list.

- Part of my trouble is that dicts are not ordered

How would you go about building the list?

Comment: "Part of my trouble is that dicts are not ordered" -- so why not using [OrderdDicts](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right of course.
I was not aware of this option.
RTPM, I should have.
Read the Python Manual

Answer (score 0):

So, following Hans's advice, I turned to OrderedDicts, from the collections module

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

then build OrderedDicts explicitly instead of dicts. They are not prettyprintable, and so harder to debug, but they do the job right.

So, thanks Hans.

I also ended up using recursion after all to place the lists in the right place.